# 2d arrays in c, unexpected value when the values are checked

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

This isn't the entire program, just snippets of it that are (as far as I can see) causing issues, I'll update if more is needed

I need to get a rectangular array of 0's in order to simulate a grid

```
int Length, Height, NumberOfParticles, Direction, validInput, StartXPosition, StartYPosition;
int *LatticeHeight;
int **Lattice;

LatticeHeight = (int*)malloc(Height*sizeof(int));

/* 
    Check for memory allocation failure 
*/

if(LatticeHeight==NULL)
{
    printf("\nMemory allocation failure. Exiting ...\n");
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

Lattice = (int**)malloc(Length*sizeof(LatticeHeight));

/* 
    Check for memory allocation failure again 
*/

if(Lattice==NULL)
{
    printf("\nMemory allocation failure. Exiting ...\n");
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Then there is some input validation which I've left out, but ultimately it gets a value for Height and Length

```
int i,j;
for(i=1; i<Height; i++)
{
    LatticeHeight[i] = 0;
}

for(j=0; j<Length; j++)
{
    Lattice[j] = LatticeHeight;
}

for(i=0;i<Height;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<Length;j++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",Lattice[i][j]);
    }
}
```

This print statement returns

```
139064
0
0
0
139064
0
0
0
139064
0
0
0
139064
0
0
0
```

Could anyone explain why?

Comment: What output where you expecting instead?

Comment: 16 zeros, which is what I got after Bhargav's pointed out that I had started by for loop from 1 instead of 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have started your loop from `1`

```
for(i=1; i<Height; i++)
{
    LatticeHeight[i] = 0;
}
```

Change it to this

```
for(i=0; i<Height; i++)
{
    LatticeHeight[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: @Aaron Be careful, Be very careful